# WSL and bash command

Tags: bash, dart, flutter, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I downloaded the flutter SDK, and have set the environment virable so that I can use the *flutter* command. On the Windows command prompt, it works well, but I work with the WSL. So when I launch the command prompt, I always launch *bash* command to switch to the linux environment. But there, the "flutter" command doesnt work and I understand that it's normal.

It displays :

```
/mnt/c/Users/Kamel/flutter/bin/flutter: line 5: $'\r': command not found
/mnt/c/Users/Kamel/flutter/bin/flutter: line 6: $'\r': command not found
/mnt/c/Users/Kamel/flutter/bin/flutter: line 14: $'\r': command not found
: invalid optionel/flutter/bin/flutter: line 15: set: -
set: usage: set [-abefhkmnptuvxBCHP] [-o option-name] [--] [arg ...]
/mnt/c/Users/Kamel/flutter/bin/flutter: line 16: $'\r': command not found
': not a valid identifierr/bin/flutter: line 17: unset: `CDPATH
/mnt/c/Users/Kamel/flutter/bin/flutter: line 18: $'\r': command not found
/mnt/c/Users/Kamel/flutter/bin/flutter: line 19: syntax error near unexpected token `$'{\r''
'mnt/c/Users/Kamel/flutter/bin/flutter: line 19: `function follow_links() {
```

So I wanted to know if a way to use the commands I have on Windows, on the WSL, existed or not ? Do I really have to install everything on WSL ? Isn't it possible to make a link between them ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I can understand from your question, you have installed flutter for windows and trying to access it from Ubuntu (WSL) which is wrong. They are different altogether.

You need to first install flutter in WSL, have a look at the official documentation [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux)

Comment: Ok, and it will be the case for any program that want to use with WSL, is it ?

Comment: Exactly, you got the concept.